# how to show map coordinates present in the array on map which is embedded on nodejs application

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs Web Application . Now I have  map coordinates ( latitute  , logitude ) in the array parsed in json form from the user . Now I wanted to show these coordinates marked on map ( only these coordinates ) which is embedded on website. I would be very very grateful if anyone can help me out of this . please

Comment: Leaflet and OpenStreetMap is one of many possible ways to do it.

Comment: For showing maps in UI, the best option is OpenLayer. Leaflet, on the other hand, is more straightforward, but OL is significantly richer. https://openlayers.org/

Comment: @Mr.R I remember that using openlayers client-side (without node.js) is very difficult, though not impossible

Comment: Node.Js has nothing to present to clients. Unquestionably, OpenLayer is a client-side package you can use on your website.